# Installing STM32CubeProgrammer on macOS Big Sur

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I'm trying to install STM32CubeProgrammer on MacOS BigSur, I have followed this steps from the website: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BmnqrB/how-to-run-stm32cubeprogrammer-on-macos-catalina-10151-19b88?t=1620993010340. Although when I run the program with terminal, it gives me an error saying that I couldn't found jre folder. But when downloading from the website, it comes with the jre folder, SetupSTM32CubeProgrammer-2.7.0.exe and SetupSTM32CubeProgrammer-2.7.0.app.

This is the error line:

```
JRE Folder not found!
```

[jre not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wISVe.png)

Answer (score 9):

macOS GUI setup doesn't work, although seems it can be executed via packaged console executable.
Use appropriate version for the command:

```
./SetupSTM32CubeProgrammerx.y.z.app/Contents/MacOs/SetupSTM32CubeProgrammer-x_y_z_macos
```

Source: [ST Community](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000aI8bS/it-is-on-my-macos-not-possible-to-install-stm32cubeprogrammer-big-sur-1121-i-get-the-notice-that-the-file-is-damaged-i-tried-it-several-times-what-is-happening-i-saw-that-in-2019-2020-this-problem-often-was-mentioned-how-comebest-regards)

Comment: See: https://gist.github.com/csukuangfj/bfe2be78eda3a24a5164005b1092c94b#7-stm32cubeprogrammer